# code for Addition three minus one variable numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, python-2.7

How to get from a list [7,0,8] from [7, 0, 8]? in python

This is my code

```
l3=input()
l5=l3.translate({Ord("["):None})
l1=l5.translate({Ord("]"):None})

l6=input()
l7=l6.translate({Ord("["):None})
l2=l7.translate({Ord("]"):None})

la1=list(l1.strip().split(","))
la2=list(l2.strip().split(","))
la1=la1[::-1]
la2=la2[::-1]

l11=""
l22=""
for I in la1:
    l11+=str(I)
for I in la2:
    l22+=str(I)
l555=[]
l111=int(l11)
l222=int(l22)
#print(l111)
#print(l222)
l333=l111+l222
l444=str(l333)
l444=l444[::-1]
for I in l444:
    l555.append(int(I))
print(l555)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> s = input()
[7, 0, 8]
>>> type(s)
<class 'str'>
>>> xs = literal_eval(s)
>>> xs
[7, 0, 8]
>>> type(xs)
<class 'list'>
>>> type(xs[0])
<class 'int'>
```

Answer (score 0):

To parse the `str` as a `list`, use `str.split(',')` and then cast each number to an `int`:

```py
s = input()
l = list(map(int,s[1:-1].split(',')))
print(l)
```

If that's too hard to read, try this:

```py
s = input()
no_brackets = s[1:-1] #remove first and last character
str_list = no_brackets.split(',')
l = []
for n in str_list:
    l.append(int(n))
```

Also, try to use better variable names; it's quite hard to follow your code.